# php - closure within a closure - is there a better way?

Tags: php, sql, recursion, closures

I'm using an array of key-value pairs (with the values possibly arrays) to construct a WHERE statement for a SQL query.

The key-values pairs get turned into `key` = 'value' with AND put between them, but if the value is an array, that in turn is imploded into OR conditions.

```
private function constructWhereStatement() {

  if (!isset($this->where) || !is_array($this->where)) {
     return 'WHERE 1';
  }

  array_walk($this->where, function(&$value, $key) {

     if (is_array($value)) {

        array_walk($value, function (&$v, $k, $key){
           $v = "`$key` = '$v'";
        }, $key);

        $value = "(" . implode(' OR ', $value) . ")";
     } else {
        $value = "`$key` = '$value'";
     }
  });
  return "WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $this->where);
}
```

So, `['side' => 'left', 'type' => ['page', 'dropdown']]` will return:

```
WHERE `side` = 'left' AND (`type` = 'page OR `type` = 'dropdown')
```

Is there a better way to do this? With recursion, perhaps?

Comment: Is there a better way of converting key/value pairs into a WHERE statement... There are different ways, but I wouldn't say that they are **better**. However, you could take a look at how the bigger PHP frameworks/ORM solutions handle things like this. For example, [Laravel Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent) has a decent solution IMO. You can construct a query using a query builder, with things like `->whereId(1)->orWhere('sum', '>', 300)`

Comment: I'm asking more about whether there is a better way to do a double closure like this. It seems like there might be a really clever recursive way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe use IN ()

```
WHERE `side` = 'left' AND type IN('type','dropdown')
```